# Combining two rows with different row names in dataframe R

Tags: r, sum, rows

I have a dataf rame with 5 columns and 14 rows. I would like to sum all the values of the rows "Barnacle nauplii" and "Echinoderm larvae" to create a new row called "Meroplanktonic larvae". Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can achive this?

My data frame looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible code for your dataset. You can use `dput(your_dataset)` and share it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't provide a reproducible code for your dataset, it is a bit hard to answer, but something like this should work:

```r
aggregate(df, list(Class = replace(df$Class, df$Class %in% c("Barnacle nauplii","Echinoderm larvae"), "Meroplanktonic larvae")), sum)
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I get this error: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument

Comment: @HMatt unless you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) then it is very hard to debug any errors you get.

Comment: @HMatt can you provide a reproducible example of your data ?